# vmware debian sid gnome mouse not working keyboard is fine

Tags: debian, gnome, mouse

I have a issue in debian sid with the gnome desktop environment where my mouse does not work after login. My keyboard is still fully functional and I have tried reinstalling gnome and gdm3 through a tty. I have the latest guest tools for vmware workstation player 12 installed. I have checked the error logs and have found nothing of use (if you need/would like to see the logs just comment about which you need ex. xorg, user, etc.)

My installation is fully up to date.

Just to clarify the mouse works fine until I log into gnome at which point it stops working.

I am using this virtual machine on a laptop and have tried my touchpad but it does not respond either.

The mouse/touchpad does not respond to clicking either how ever if I open a terminal in gnome via ctrl+alt+t the cursor will update to show an "I" as if it is typing but it is still completely unresponsive to my mouse/touchpad.

I have at this point no idea how to fix this issue and I am asking if anyone has any idea how to fix/debug this issue?

UPDATE

This issue is caused by vmware not having support for Xorg 7.7 and until they fix the issue there is little that can be done.

If you would like to try playing with Xorg 7.7 configurations and settings then maybe [this website](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/xorg-config.html) could help.

Comment: just got the same issue after a dist-upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Surprisingly, uninstalling `xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse` helps.

```
apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
```

Comment: this may not be a real fix but until vmware adds support for Xorg 7.7 I don't think there will be a decent fix available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have the same issue.

I found the following is workaround.

`$ sudo -E startx`

But, this workaround have a lot of problems.
I hope completly solution.

UPDATE

The following workaround is better, but it has problems too.

`$ sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on Debian 11/sid VM: keyboard - ok, mouse is not working.
There issue was that I used `genericcloud` image for the system installation, the cloud kernel which is included in the image probably not intended to run graphical interface and does not support a mouse.

The solution was to install standard kernel and remove cloud one:

```
apt-get install linux-image-amd64
apt-get purge 'linux-image-*cloud-amd64'
```